# Task manager says i'm using 1.3GB of memory but Sci Tech MemProfiler says ~200MB?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I'm having a problem with Task Manager saying a C# (WPF) Application is using an enormous amount of memory (We have seen it up to 5-6GB when left overnight) but the Sci Tech Memory Profiler (And the built in VS one) says I am using 200 - 300 MB at the peak times.

The application in question is currently engaged in an optimizing operation that does do plenty of memory allocations and the garbage collector appears to be busy.

But why would the two memory usage reports be so wildly divergent? Is this even something we should worry about? Customers will probably notice it and panic so it would be good to get to the bottom of why they are so divergent if it isn't a problem, and fix it if it is.

[image: Task Manager Reported Memory Usage]

[image: Snap Shot of memory usage from SciTech Profiler]

Comment: A .NET application would use both managed and native resources. Thus, it would be OK for the two to tell different usage, as Task Manager reports the total of both, while Sci Tech might only focus on the managed. Check the documentation of Sci Tech for more details on the numbers it reports.

Comment: That might explain it, but I didn't think we were using unmanaged anything in the system.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what is going on, but after some further investigation it appears that .NET runtime will actually quite happily hang onto memory for use in future allocations rather than free it back to the OS until such a time as the OS is pushed for memory.

It turns out all of our memory was getting into the Gen #2 allocation heap, but because the CPU is busy doing a lot of work, the Gen #2 garbage collection isnt ever getting run in idle time.

So the allocation grows over time until the machine decides it has to do a Gen #2 GC and that frees a lot of it.

That is our working theory anyway.